# Rollback to previous version is giving error

Tags: cme, 5.3

I am using Tridion 5.3 GA and in CME I am trying to rollback a component from a previous version. (Current Version 20, and trying to rollback from 16). Doing this is resulting me in below error:

```
Unable to rollback Component (tcm:7-4565-v16).
The title is not unique.

Error Code:
0x8004026D (-2147220883)

Call stack:
VersioningCommon.AssertForRollbackItem
VersioningCommon.RollbackItem
ComponentBL.Rollback
Component.RollBack
```

The event viewer also has only this entry and no other error/warning/information logged in.

Few other things that I have tried/checked:

- Checked the name of the component has never got changed
- Open both the version of component and compare the entire content and there is no single difference in them
- Tried both the Rollback option (Copy without delete and Copy with deletion of subsequent version) - both result in same error
- Tried with few other components and they are getting rolled back with out any issue - so this is happening with few specific components only
- Tried rolling back from other versions (instead of version 16), but same error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Further, If I change the name of the component in the publication where it has been created, it let me allow to change but now if I want to even open the component back and try to change its name back to the previous, it does not allow me and say there is a conflict with . All these TCM URI are of this component only with it localized in different child publication. This is weird as this is not inline with BP concept and also, any other component in the same way I can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug with Tridion R5.3.

- Create a Component in Master with Name (say Test)
- Localize in Child and Rename it  to some other name (say Test1)
- Create a component in Child with same name as in Master .i.e Test

Now in master you can't check out and rollback the component.

So basically, it requires to resolve this dependency and figure out why someone in the world have done that. The option left to me is either resolve the dependency on this component and correctly use the component localized and updated from Master itself instead of creating it again with the same name in Child publication (A very big task) or just live with it and rename the localized component again to some other name not conflicting with master, remove older version of it in Child publication.

I hope it will help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that the item name that you are rolling back to doesn't conflict with something elsewhere in the blueprint.

Comment: Thanks Dom. The error actually suggests that but the name of the item in current version and the version to which we are trying to rollback is absolutely same. So it should not be in conflict with anything in blueprint as well

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error then?

Comment: I mean to say the error in question above and specifically the "title is not unique" thing. I have also updated the question if it can help me getting some more views of this.

Comment: So it seems something allowed an item to have an invalid name--at least two items, from different publications, have the same title, but are different items in the BluePrint. You can probably roll back if you cut & paste the item to a different folder. Otherwise, find the offending item using search and/or the BluePrint viewer, if available (which was an extension in R5.3 if I remember correctly--not sure if it did just publications or items as well).

Comment: The point is that if you renamed a localized version of a different item in the same folder, and the item you're rolling back is called the same thing in the rollback version, you'll get this message.