# How can we have a version 0 for a component in Items Table

Tags: content-manager, 5.3

I have been trying to analyze a issue related to error while trying to rollback a component ([Details Here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/rollback-to-previous-version-is-giving-error)).

Now while trying to dig further, I was amazed to see entries in the `Items` table of Content Manager DB. It have two records for the same component one with latest version and another with `Version`field value as 0. Further the `Modification Date` of the component is also exactly same. Please refer the screen shot of the table as below:

[image]

Can someone explain in what scenario it could be possible to have a component version save in duplicate at exactly the same time stamp and also with `Version` field value as 0 so that I can dig further in the issue.

I am using Tridion R5.3.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this causing an issue in anyway? Or are you just curious? Version 0 is typically the "editable" version of a component, which may be different from the last checked in version.

Comment: Not sure if it is something causing a problem, I was just trying to figure the issue that I was not able to rollback this component or do undo checkout so thinking if it is an issue.

Comment: Took a quick look in my database - I have a version 0 for each item that is currently _checked out_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version 0 - also sometimes visible in CME URLs as `tcm:1-2-3-v0` - is the *editable* version of an item. Each item that is currently checked-out will have a record with this version number in the database and everytime you hit Save (not Save & Close), this version will be updated.

Once you click Save & Close, a new major version will be created with the contents of the version 0.

This of course will be different when you have workflow enabled - in that case, there is still a version 0 (with the same meaning of *editable* version), but Save & Close will create a new *minor* version (x.1, x.2, etc).